# Set value based on count distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say that I have the following data on `tbl`:

```
Label | Color
X     | color1
X     | color1
Y     | color1
Y     | color2
```

The sample output should be:

```
X | color1
Y | misc
```

So basically, if the respective label only has one type of color I want it to be that type, else I want it to say `misc`.

I did the following which didn't work as I wanted, which the next step would be applying a `case` into the `count`:

```
select label,count(distinct color) from @tbl
group by label,color
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `MAX` or `MIN` to get the single value to use where appropriate.

And should be grouping just by `label`

```
select label,
       case when count(distinct color) = 1 THEN MAX(color) ELSE 'misc' END
from @tbl
group by label
```

It will generally be more efficient though to check if max equals min rather than doing a distinct count

```
select label,
       case when MAX(color) = MIN(color) THEN MAX(color) ELSE 'misc' END
from @tbl
group by label
```

There isn't much to choose between the two in efficiency if you have an index on `label, color` but if you only have an index on `(label) INCLUDE (color)` or have no useful index at all the `MAX`/`MIN` approach will have to do less work (just needs a single grouping operation on `label` and to keep track of two values within each group - not identify the number of unique values in each group)